# Make merge multi-core able?

Tags: r, merge, multiprocessing

The following line takes very long to compute in my code:

```
merge(df, df2[df2['field'] == someValue,], by="someField", all.x=1)
```

There could be a way to make this multi-core able, by splitting the first data frame in several parts, assign a core to each of the parts that will try to merge it with the second df, and then attach the results.

However, I didn't manage to find code that makes merges multi-core-able. Does that mean the idea is rubbish? Is there some package / snippet to make it work?

Comment: Just use `data.table` or `dplyr`. It won't be multicore, but it will be faster.

Comment: Your question isn't reproducible, but you can try doing something like `library(data.table);
setkey(setDT(df), someField);
df[setkey(setDT(df2), someField)["someValue"]]`